# Is there a way to download Xcode on its own?

Tags: xcode, ios

Is there a way to download Xcode on its own, without the iOS SDK? I have a very slow internet connection and this would take 3 or so hours to download, also I don't need the iOS SDK at all.

Any help would be appreciated!! :)

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-developer/44390183#44390183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Xcode (seemingly on its own) now from the Mac App Store now:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214

Answer (score 3):

I see there's a way to get xcode developer tools 3.2.2 without IOS, it's a 744 MB download.

Once you login to your developer account you'll see the 3.2.4 w/ios download, but if you click on "Developer Downloads" under "Development Resources" you'll get to the download area.  Then click on "Developer tools" on the right side navigation and it'll be on the following page in the list.

Comment: I have Xcode 3.1 at the moment, but I'd like 3.2.4 if possible, thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah i dont see the 3.2.4 version, only the 3.2.2 .