# Xamarin.iOS: The app cannot be installed on simulator with the Xcode-beta-9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, updates

My Xamarin.iOS app can be built but cannot be installed in debug mode with Xcode-beta simulator. When I hit the run button simulator (IPhone 7 11.0 - also tried other types) does not start and gives error. I cannot debug right now and test  iOS 11.0 compatibity of my app. Any help will be appreciated. Here is the output:

> error HE0003: 
>   Could not load the framework 'CoreSimulator' (path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/CoreSimulator): not found.

Comment: Xcode 9 GM Seed is available. Try using it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-beta-or-xcode-9-gm-seed-version-without-premium-dev/44390183#44390183

Comment: I tried but it also does not include 
 ~/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework

Comment: Have you run Xcode since downloading it? It needs to be run once to configure everything.

Comment: Yeah I did it as the xamarin ios 11.0 release page has suggested. Now, it resolved the reason for not working was because of not being supported by xamarin at the time apple release xcode.

Comment: As commented in this link, seems not all VS for Mac versions support XCode9: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58417

Comment: After Xcode-9.0 stable release there isn't a problem anymore but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Had the same error after updating to Xcode 9.2 but still needed to update Visual Studio and Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: @ChristopherStephan, I have the same issue, Xcode 9.2, Mac VS: 7.3.3, Win VS:15.2 (26430.16)
Which version solved this issue to you?

Comment: Xcode 9.0 worked for me. Also, this was temporary and there were continuous updates when I have been dealing with this issue. Can u specify your problem?

Comment: I can run xamarin ios app on the simulator, properly connected to the mac, but when I try to open 'LaunchScreen.storyboard', I got error: `The iOS Designer requires an active connection to a Mac server. Please connect to a Mac to enable the designer.` Opening the log: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/CoreSimulator` I have latest Mac VS, xcode 9.2, but my win VS is a bit outdated (15.2) Maybe I should install 15.6?

Comment: It might be about your windows vs packages. Have u tried to edit storyboard on a mac? I think you should try

Comment: Ok, interesting, I restarted both machine -> still did not work. Waited some minutes, tried again, and **surprise** , it works now, I see the storyboard editor on windows/xamarin. Xamarin mysteries...