# warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

Tags: ios, string, substring, swift4, xcode9.1

[characters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540072-characters) - an instance property of String, is deprecated from with [Xcode 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-9-3-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-d/44390183#44390183)

It was very useful to get a substring from String by using the `characters` property but now it has been deprecated and Xcode suggests to use `substring`. I've tried to check around SO questions and apple developer tutorials/guidelines for the same. But could not see any solution/alternate as suggested.

Here is warning message:

> **'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring**

[image]

I've so many string operations are performed/handled using property `characters`.

Anyone have any idea/info about this update?

Comment: Here is an [interesting article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-strings-for-swift-4/) about the `String` changes from Swift 3 to 4 and please read also [SE0163](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md)

Comment: try to use [`count`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894926-count) instead.

Comment: If you were using `string.characters.forEach` the new API is `string.forEach { char in  process(char) }`

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Swift 4 introduced changes on string API.

You can just use `!stringValue.isEmpty` instead of `stringValue.characters.count > 0`

for more information you get the sample from [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-strings-for-swift-4/)

for e.g

```
let edit = "Summary"
edit.count   // 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But can I have detail reference of sub string. This is just sample example, I've so many other operations dealing with characters

Comment: Please check detail information from here. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: let greeting = "Hello, world!"
let index = greeting.index(of: ",") ?? greeting.endIndex
let beginning = greeting[..<index]

Comment: Online reference for [Substring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring).

Comment: Never use count > 0 to check if a collection is empty. There is a property on Collection called isEmpty exactly for that. From the docs **When you need to check whether your collection is empty, use the isEmpty property instead of checking that the count property is equal to zero. For collections that don’t conform to RandomAccessCollection, accessing the count property iterates through the elements of the collection.**

Comment: `extension Collection {var isNotEmpty: Bool {get {return self.isEmpty ? false : true}}}`

Comment: Is it backward compatible? I've few 3.0.2 version to support as well.

Comment: @Jonny `extension Collection { var isNotEmpty: Bool { return !isEmpty } }`

Answer (score 89):

Swift 4 vs Swift 3 examples:

```
let myString = "test"

for char in myString.characters {print(char) } // Swift 3
for char in myString { print(char) } // Swift 4

let length = myString.characters.count // Swift 3
let length = myString.count // Swift 4
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The question is about the replacement for string.characters.count, not the replacement for comparing to zero; that's only mentioned in the screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

One of the most common cases for manipulating strings is with JSON responses. In this example I created an extension in my watch app to drop the last (n) characters of a Bitcoin JSON object.

**Swift 3:**

```
func dropLast(_ n: Int = 0) -> String {
    return String(characters.dropLast(n))
```

Xcode 9.1 Error Message:

> 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

Xcode is telling us to use the string variable or method *directly*.

**Swift 4:**

```
func dropLast(_ n: Int = 0) -> String {
    return String(dropLast(n))
    }
```

Complete Extension:

```
extension String {
    func dropLast(_ n: Int = 0) -> String {
        return String(dropLast(n))
    }

    var dropLast: String {
        return dropLast()
    }
}
```

**Call:**

```
print("rate:\(response.USDRate)")
let literalMarketPrice = response.USDRate.dropLast(2)
print("literal market price: \(literalMarketPrice)")
```

**Console:**

```
//rate:7,101.0888 //JSON float
//literal market price: 7,101.08 // JSON string literal
```

**Additional Examples:**

- `print("Spell has \(invisibleSpellName.count) characters.")`
- `return String(dropLast(n))`
- `return String(removeLast(n))`

**Documentation:**

You'll often be using common methods such as `dropLast()` or `removeLast()` or `count` so here is the explicit Apple documentation for each method.

[droplast()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893517-droplast)

[removelast()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2892866-removelast)

[counting characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297)

Answer (score 3):

Use this `characters` because `String` stopped being a collection in Swift 2.0. However this is still valid code in Swift 4 but is no longer necessary now that `String` is a `Collection` again.

For example a Swift 4 `String` now has a direct count property that gives the character count:

```
// Swift 4
let spString = "Stack"
spString.count           // 5
```

Examples for String and SubString.

> String

Swift 4 `String` now directly get Element that gives the first character of String: <s>`(string.characters.first)`</s>

```
let spString = "Stack"
let firstElement = spString.first   //S
```

> SubString

Using SubString get first character.

```
let spstring = "Welcome"
let indexStartOfText = spstring.index(spstring.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let sub = spstring.substring(to: indexStartOfText)
print(sub) //W
```

Comment: I want to get first character of string so I want to know that which way should I use let firstElement = spString.first or Substring?

Comment: @Pulkit Better to use `.first` because if string is `""` empty. it will only return nil but `substring` will produce error.

Comment: how to convert this line of code to swift 4 'AuthorImageText = String(val.characters[(AuthorName.startIndex)]).capitalized'

Comment: @Pulkit just remove `.characters` enough

Answer (score 2):

That warning is just a top of the iceberg, there were a loot of string changes, strings are again a collection of characters, but we got soemthing new and cool, subStrings :)

This is a great read about this:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-strings-for-swift-4/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove characters
For example:

stringValue.characters.count 
to
stringValue.count

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code for dictionary grouping without using  { $0.characters.first! }.

```
let cities = ["Shanghai": 24_256_800, "Karachi": 23_500_000, "Beijing": 21_516_000, "Seoul": 9_995_000]
let groupedCities = Dictionary(grouping: cities.keys) { $0.first! }
print(groupedCities)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func validatePhoneNumber(number:String) -> Bool{
    if number.count < 10. //deprecated ->(number.characters.count)
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

You use directly .count and characters is deprecated.