# InterFace builder is behaving weird in xcode9 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

My interface Builder is doing weird things in xcode 9 beta is anyone know where the problem is? see the image below

[image: look at the image]

Comment: It's beta. so huge possibility of having bugs. :)

Comment: Try with stable version of latest Xcode 9.2 and see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-devel/44390183#44390183