# 'LABiometryType' is only available on iOS 11.0.1 or newer

Tags: ios, xcode, face-id, localauthentication, xcode9.3-beta

[Xcode 9.3 (beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-9-3-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-d/44390183#44390183) showing an error for enum `LABiometryType`, which was working fine with `Xcode 9.2` with check `available(iOS 11.0, *)`.

Here is error message:

> 'LABiometryType' is only available on iOS 11.0.1 or newer

[image]

Here is my existing code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.faceID) {
        //localizedReason = "Unlock using Face ID"
        print("FaceId support")
    } else if (laContext.biometryType == LABiometryType.touchID) {
        //localizedReason = "Unlock using Touch ID"
        print("TouchId support")
    } else {
        //localizedReason = "Unlock using Application Passcode"
        print("No Biometric support")
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Problem is: If I replace `#available(iOS 11.0, *)` with `#available(iOS 11.0.1, *)` as suggested in error message, then how to handle Face-id biometry (`LABiometryType.faceID`) for iOS 11.0.

Comment: The Apple docs are incorrect about the availability of `LABiometry` type beginning with iOS 11.0+... or at least the omission of the 11.0.1+ specificity is misleading. At least Xcode 9.3 now shows compiler warnings about it. I wound up discovering this myself through a small of set crashlogs reading `-[LAContext biometryType] unrecognized selector sent to instance` that only occurred on iOS 11.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to handle Face ID on iOS 11.0 because the iPhone X was released with iOS 11.0.1. There is no iOS device on iOS 11.0 that has Face ID capabilities.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_11_0 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_X

Comment: The iPhone X was publicly launched with iOS 11.1.0 to my recollection. I believe this Wikipedia page is mistaken. I would suspect that beta versions of the iPhone X uses for internal testing and press events were seeded with iOS 11.0.x prior to Nov 3 launch date. But otherwise, yes, FaceID does not need to be handled in iOS 11.0.0

Comment: No. The inital batch of iPhone X shipped with 11.0.1 installed. I had such an iPhone myself. Here is another reference: https://9to5mac.com/2017/11/03/ios-11-2-beta-iphone-x/

Comment: Cool I didn't know. Thanks for the second link ^_^