# Waiting for {simulator/device} to start

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9.3-beta

With [Xcode 9.3 (beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-9-3-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-d/44390183#44390183), I'm facing an issue with Xcode tool, while I try to build/run the application (project) for the first time, after Xcode launch/start.

Several times, it prevents project build with the message on status bar:

> Waiting for iPhone-X to start

While my simulator is already started and working (There is no any activity, going on, in the simulator).

Here is reference snapshot:

[image]

As a temporary solution, I force close Xcode (9.3) and start again.

[image]

Is there anyone facing the same issue with Xcode 9.3 beta?

**Update**: *Same issue in Xcode 9.3-Beta 2 also.*

Comment: why are you still in the beta version of Xcode? you should definitely update this will hopefully fix this problem!

Comment: @Fozoro - Dear it's latest beta for Xcode tool [New Tools for 64-bit Support in Xcode 9.3 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01242018d) and I'm associated with R&D division in my organization, hence I must analyze upcoming changes in technology in advance.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry didn't pay attention, I thought you where using the Xcode beta that was released this summer

Comment: It works the first time for me, but subsequent to that fails. I have to remember to quit XCode after first run, or I have to force-quit when it stalls the second time

Comment: This is a known issue with the beta.

Comment: This issue still occurs with Xcode 9.3 beta 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is How I fixed:

> Due to quirks (most likely Simulator bugs) in the Simulator launching on both Xcode 8 and 9, there is no common code to have it launch successfully on both Xcodes. Through experimenting, I have found these to be most reliable:

#### Xcode 9:

```
killall Simulator
xcrun simctl boot <device_id>
open `xcode-select -p`/Applications/Simulator.app
```

#### Xcode 8:

```
killall Simulator
xcrun simctl shutdown booted
xcrun instruments -w <device_id>
```

refer: [[iOS 11][Xcode 9] launch, install, start hangs Simulator #209](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim/issues/209)

Answer (score 1):

What (most of the time) works for me, is first launch it on a device. Kill it and then run it on a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the previous Xcode's version of Simulator running when you attempt to run Simulator from the new Xcode, because Xcode will attempt to use that one. (each Xcode bundles it's own Simulator)

Shut down the old Simulator, and try again.

Also, make sure in Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools is pointing to the current Xcode build.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me : open the simulator device manually (File -> Open Device -> pick the one). Then restart it by going to Device -> restart. 
Then try rerunning on xcode.

Answer (score -2):

I've experienced this lots of times especially in beta releases, until I discovered a 'hack' or perhaps a nice way to prevent such issue. But before that, I might add as well this SO link that has a compilation of `.dmg` Xcode download links. [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

TL;DR **In order to prevent this kind of issue, just stop debugging or click on STOP button before building/running your application.**